# requests.get() throws an exception in aws lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, boto3, aws-serverless

I'm not able to make HTTP calls from python based lambda function hosted on AWS and managed through Serverless framework.

I've tried using `botocore.vendored` requests module but it shows deprecation warning and suggested to use the requests module itself.

```
url = V2_URL + '/api/analytics/validate/' + smId
headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print('Result: ')
print(response.content)
```

In Cloudwatch, I see this stack trace:

```
[ERROR] UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 97, in wrapped_handler
    return user_handler(event, context)
  File "src/authorize.py", line 21, in validate
    principal_id = verify_token(whole_auth_token, event['pathParameters']['smId'])
  File "src/authorize.py", line 38, in verify_token
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/var/task/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 384, in wrapper
    if response:
```

Comment: Assign to `response` instead of `result`: `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`.

Comment: That was a typo, check my comment on first answer.

Comment: Your traceback shows that the execution stops at ` if response:` and yet it is not part of your posted code. Please post your actual code if you want us to help.

Comment: Well if you noticed, that part of code is not part of my function and is auto-generated by serverless sdk.

Comment: I see. This is indeed interesting and likely a bug of the SDK then.

Comment: I agree this looks like a bug in the SDK and the SDK bug is masking your real issue.  (It looks like the SDK doesn't handle exceptions properly).  You might try to put a try/except around your code and print out the exception that your code is raising.

Comment: Fixed in the latest release of serverless SDK. Thank you, everyone, for the valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @blhsing and @Mark A pointed out, there was a bug in version 3.1.1 of `@serverless/enterprise-plugin` package. Upgrading it to version 3.1.2 solved the issue for me. All I had to do was `npm i -g serverless` and it took care of itself.

Details of issue here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6801